# The view function for 'authen.delete_tracker' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

```
flask code

@bp.route('/delete/<int:id>')

@login_required

def delete_tracker(id):
      
        if Trackers.user_id == current_user.id:
        trackers = Trackers.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        print(trackers)
        db.session.delete(trackers)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("authen.dashboard"))  

 
Html code- look for /delete url t bottom there is the error

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<nav class="sidenav">

  <div class="main-buttons">


    <a class="nav-link active" id="trackers" aria-current="page" href="/dashboard">Trackers</a>


    <a class="nav-link active" id="goals" aria-current="page" href="/goals">Goals</a>
    <div>
</nav>

<div id="dashbar">
  <nav class="navbar bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Add Tracker
      </button>
      <form method="POST">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a Tracker</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="tracker_name" class="col-form-label">Tracker Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tracker_name" name="tracker_name"
                  placeholder="Enter a Tracker name">

                <div class="from-fieldset" style="width:200px;">
                  <label for="tracker_type" class="form-label">Choose a Tracker type:</label>
                  <select id="tracker_type" name="tracker_type">
                    <option value="">choose Tracker type</option>
                    {% for t in data_trackers %}
                    <option value="{{t.name}}">{{t.name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <label for="tracker_description " class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tracker_description" name="tracker_description"
                      placeholder="Enter Description">

                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light border-dark">Submit</button>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>


      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>


<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container-tracker">
    {% for track in user.trackers %}
    <div class="tra">


      <h3 id="trackername"> {{track.tracker_name}}</h3>


      <div class="dropdown-container" tabindex="-1">

        <form method="GET" action="/delete/{{track.id}}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <div class="three-dots"></div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">
            <div>Records and Graphs</div>
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>



</div>


{% endblock %}
```

( in form method=GET , the delete url is there and the flask code is at top for that endpoint
if I remove if condition in the delete_tracker() fucntion that is if user.id==current_user.id then I will get a different error that is , this is for session 2nd but this is 3rd session something like this, so my file I want to delete is different session )

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change your line

```
@bp.route('/delete/<int:id>')
```

to

```
@bp.route('/delete/<track.id>')
```

Comment: I can change it will return an error , i did it to convert the number to integer there as the endpoint will return id as string